# Dlopen Error in Linux while using GLES 2 PowerVR libs?

Tags: linux

I was using powervr sdk gles 2 libs in linux in gamekit/ogre for building an application. I get the error 
"dlopen tries:libGL.so" after which application crashes.
I tried debugging using DDD etc but couldnt isolate much.
How do I fix this in linux(Ubuntu 10.10)?

Does linux refer to some default in built libs while running dlopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library name like libGL.so is only used for linking at compile time. When run-time linking, you should be using the SONAME; something like libGL.so.1. If that library has any dependencies, they must also be available. Try running 'ldd /path/to/libGL.so.1' and see if there are any missing libraries. Also, make sure that you're pointing to the correct libGL; there could be a few versions on your system, each optimized for different graphics cards.